# How to prevent calendar widget from floating while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to prevent calendar widget from floating on screen when scrolling ?
I am using Jquery datepicker.

Comment: you may try the solution below

Answer (score 1):

```
var datePicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker();

$(".demo").scroll(function() {
  datePicker.datepicker('hide');
  $('#datepicker').blur();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  datePicker.datepicker('hide');
  $('#datepicker').blur();
});
```

This will hide the date picker when container div or window is scrolled. here is a working fiddle [check solution](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/m6A5q/2/)

`$('#datepicker').blur();` will come in handy, when user scrolls .demo calendar hides but the input is still focused, so when he scrolls back he can become confused. So as I blur it he will have to click on the input again and date picker will show up.

Comment: Thanks that helps a bit. bu cant we fix this calendar widget to input, even when we scroll?

Comment: @ak38 what do you mean input while scrolling

Comment: @ Hudhaifa Yoosuf  input means the form textbox which is datepicker here.

Comment: @ak38 you mean you want the input box to stay fixed in the same position  while the page is scrolling ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried every answer I could find on the net. I eventually just did this to hide the datepicker upon scroll:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var datepickerWin = $("id$=txtboxDate").datepicker({});
  
  document.addEventListener("wheel", function(event){ //anytime the mousewheel is scrolled
    datepickerWin.datepicker("hide");
    $("id$=txtboxDate").blur(); //so we can remove the mouse cursor from the input field
  });
  
  $("id=btnDate").click(function() {
    datepickerWin.datepicker("show");
  });
  
  
  
});
```